# Evolução do modelo de dados controlada por código

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, automatização, integração-contínua

Em um cenário no qual a aplicação é deployada para produção através de um pipe line executado por um servidor de CI, onde o servidor realiza as seguintes tarefas:

- Instala as dependências de front end e back end. Executa outras tarefas    definidas no automatizador de tarefas como, minificação de
  arquivos alteração em código e redução da qualidade de imagens e
  vídeos.
- Executa os testes automatizados.
- Roda as migrações no banco de dados secundário.
- Realiza um dumping do servidor de banco de dados primário em produção.
- Restaura o dumping do banco de dados primário no secundário considerando o novo modelo de dados.
- Atualiza os arquivos nos servidores de aplicação.
- Torna o banco de dados secundário em primário e atualiza o antigo primário.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Considerando que estou usando um banco de dados relacional, ao executar as migrações no banco ele não pode estar em operação? (Por isso imagino que devo atualizar um secundário e depois transforma-lo em primário). No caso de eu executar as migrations em um banco que está operacional recebendo escritas o banco para de executar minhas operações de escritas ou vai controlar elas de maneira ordenada através de seu controle de concorrência?

Estou tentando encontrar uma metodologia segura porém descentralizada para evoluir o banco de dados continuamente junto da aplicação, sem depender de um time de DBAs, deixando o controle automatizado direto no servidor de CI e Deploy, e a evolução do banco a controlada em código a cargo dos próprios desenvolvedores utilizando classes de migrations dentro da aplicação.

Preciso de dicas baseadas nas experiências dos colegas que tenham melhor experiência com evolução contínua automatizada.